# MySQL db - Can i use a wildcard inside a field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure if this is possible but I have a small MySql database that is used with a call screener app for my PBX.. I can add single numbers such as (555) 123-4567, however I would like to enter in entire blocks of numbers like (555) 123-???? so that any number calling from the numbers (555) 123-0000 through (555) 123-9999 would be selected in one entry. I know you can use wildcards in queries etc., but can they be used inside row or column fields?

Answer (score 0):

I think that should work, if you reverse the parameters of `like`. So if you have a table with 'number masks' to match with (assuming some table and column names here), it could look like this:

```
select * from NumberMasks m where :CallerNumber like m.Mask
```

For clarity: `:CallerNumber` is the phone number of the caller. `NumberMasks` is just an assumed name for the table, where `Mask` would be the column containing the mask to match with in the form of `(555) 123-????` as specified in the question.

Comment: how is "m" and "Mask" and ":CallerNumber" predefined ?

Comment: Revenge downvote much? `m` is the alias for the table, `:CallerNumber` is a parameter. As I wrote, these names are an assumption because I didn't get the actual table name, but their naming should be clear enough to relate to the question. Apart from that, this is basic SQL syntax which shouldn't be too hard to read, but I added a clarifying paragraph especially for you, @drtechno. ^.^